# Remove margin-right when flex-wrap is wraping elements with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a wrapper and some items within. I would like to place two items next to other in each row. I used `flexbox` to solve this.

My wrapper has the property `flex-wrap: wrap;` and my items have the property: `flex: 0 0 45%;`. So every of my items use 50% of the row (included the margins). I use `margin` to make a gap on the right side and a gap on the bottom between the items. This works almost as I expected.

Now my question: Is there a way to ignore the `margin-right` on the second item in each row (where it wraps), so the second item is also aligned to the right side of the wrapper same as the left item is. At the moment, there is also a gap at the end of the row because of the `margin-right`. I would like to remove this gap. Is this possible with pure `CSS`? `last-child` just removes the `margin-right` on the last item, but this is clear why. Is there a way to remove it on the end of the row, where the items wrap? Hope this is clear enough.

Below my snippet:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 768px;
}

.wrapper__item {
  flex: 0 0 45%;
  width: 330px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0 36px 18px 0;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Here is also a screenshot where I would like to remove the margin-right (see arrows):

[image]

Comment: There is many ways to solve this, a question though, what if there is only 1 item in e.g. the last row? ... and if, should it center, stretch, left align, ...?

Comment: @LGSon This is a good question: If there are more items in a row for example three, it must remove again the margin-right on the last item of the row, where it wraps.

Comment: Got that. What if there is 3 items per row, and a total of 10. That will leave a single item in the last row. How should that item behave? ... same size as the rest or take full width, centered or left aligned, ...?

Comment: @LGSon Same size as the rest. It shoudl be like this: On smartphone just one item and with a slider, so you can slide through it. Tablet they have to be 2 in a row 50% of the row. And 1024px and higher viepowrt 4 of it. So I can solve this easy with nth-child(2n) and nth-child(4n) it's the easiest way with medie queries. :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 768px;
  }

  .wrapper__item {
    flex: 1 0 45%;
    /*   width: 330px; */
    height: 160px;
    margin: 0 36px 18px 0;
    background-color: lightcoral;
  }

  .wrapper div:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
    <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
    <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
    <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
    <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
    <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Remove `width: 330px;` in `.wrapper__item` selector.

Modify `flex: 0 0 45%;` to `flex: 1 0 45%;` in `.wrapper__item` selector.

Add css code:

```
.wrapper div:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Hope helpful :).

Comment: This is the best solution for my requirement. Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't understand the magic but it works! Thanks. 3 years now that I am coding web apps and I still struggle to remember the how to use flexbox direction shrink grow etc. :( 
If anyone has an article with great memotechnical means, I would be very interested. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Remove `margin-right` and use `justify-content: space-between` and use `width:calc(50%-18px)`. It will give you exactly the 36px gap between your items.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 768px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper__item {
  width: calc(50% - 18px);
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Reference Link

- [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: Hi and thanks. This is not the best solution for me, because I have to use exactly 36px gap between the items. And with this solution it's not like this.

Comment: @MrBuggy then use `width: calc(50% - 18px);` Updated! it will give you a exact 36px gap between items.

Comment: tks, this is the way, extra right margin removed

Answer (score 1):

If you can handle how many items per row you can use :nth-child(2n)

Comment: This is a good solution. Please take a look on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler using `gap` css property:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 18px;
}

.wrapper__item { 
  flex: 1;           
  min-width: calc(300px - 18px); 
  height: 160px;     
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
</div>
```

It will work with important changes on item:

- `flex: 1`
- `min-width` instead of `width`

and on wrapper:

- `gap: 18px` to create a gap between elements

You can create a different gap between horizontal and vertical with: `gap: HR VR` where HR is horizontal gap, and VR is vertical gap; i.e.:
`gap: 10px 18px`
or using `column-gap` and/or `row-gap` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content: space-between` and `height` of wrapper with `align-content` optionally

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 768px;
  height: 588px;
}

.wrapper__item {
  width: 330px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The gap between the two components must be 36px.